# Efficiency of my function with Lua tables

Tags: performance, lua, lua-table

I have a question about the way I put together this piece of Lua code. 
Say, there is a function like the one below, containing 200 `myTable` tables, where the names are ordered alphabetically:

```
function loadTable(x)
    local myTable
    if x == "aaron" then myTable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
    elseif x == "bobby" then myTable = {1,3,3,4,5,8,7,8,9,1}  
    elseif x == "cory" then myTable = {1,2,3,3,3,6,7,8,9,2}
    elseif x == "devin" then myTable = {1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,9,0}          
    ...
    else 
        print("table not available") 
    end
    return myTable
end
```

and now I want to find the table corresponding to `x == "zac"` (which happens to be somewhere at the end). I use this line of code:

```
local foundTable = loadTable("zac")
```

Isnt this like not efficient at all? If it has to find the table at the very end of the function it has to go through all the previous lines of code. Is there some way to code this more efficiently in lua and find the correct table faster? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can become a lot faster by using... a table!

Simply make a table whose keys are the name of the person and the values are the table you want to load, like this:

```
local tables = {
   john = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},
   peter = {1,3,3,4,5,8,7,8,9,1},
   william = {1,2,3,3,3,6,7,8,9,2},
   victoria = {1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,9,0}
   --...
}
```

Then, instead of calling `loadTable("richard")` simply use `tables["richard"]` or `tables.richard` if the key is a valid [identifier](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.3.html)

Comment: I was afraid to mention this because he may use invalid identifiers when populating the table. But, yeah, in this scenario where only names are used, that'll work, thanks for the addition :)